# What's the idiom for creating an ever more complex solution to a problem?

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests

It means to take a (flawed) existing solution/explanation to a problem and modify it in ever more convoluted ways to make it work when the current version fails.

It comes from pre-Newtonian times when there were people working on a theory of orbital mechanics, thinking that orbits were circular rather than elliptical, and every time someone made an observation of some moon that the theory didn't handle, they bolted on a bit more math to try and account for that observation.

It was "working on circles" or "calculating orbits" or something like that.

Comment: now asking for expressions too ... good.  Change title too if you please.

Answer (score 13):

It's known as *[adding epicycles](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Adding_epicycles)*:

> **Adding epicycles** is an expression denoting ad hoc attempts to make a
>   theory conform to observations by making said theory needlessly or
>   absurdly complicated.
>
> The expression comes from a technique used by Astronomers from
>   antiquity to the early modern period (generally working with the
>   Ptolemaic system) to explain observations that planets would often
>   reverse direction in the sky. These observations made sense in a
>   Sun-centered view of the solar system, but not an Earth-centered one
>   (Heliocentric systems had greater observational problems of their own,
>   which prevented their general acceptance in antiquity).

Comment: Thank you! That's been killing me all day long and my Google-fu was failing me.

Comment: @lbf it's occasionally used in a figurative sense among people who might expect to know a bit of astronomy (IME). I have a vague recollection of hearing it used to describe embellishing a piece of music, as well